# How to return a function references from try/catch in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

in Jetpack Compose, I want to return a Function Reference in try & catch block.

The function I use (In ViewModel):

```
    fun getResult(): NoteType {
        if (canDone) {
            return NoteType(title, body, color)
        } else throw IllegalArgumentException("Not done")
    }
```

And where I use it (inside Composable):

```
        val action = try { viewModel::getResult } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException){ {} }

        Icon(
            Icons.Filled.Done,
            contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.create_screen_done),
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("done")
                .noRippleClickable (action)
                .alpha(if (!viewModel.canDone) 0.5f else 1f)
        )
```

but I end up with NullPointerException:

```
The root cause java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ReflectionReferencesGenerator.generateCallableReference(ReflectionReferencesGenerator.kt:68)
null: KtCallableReferenceExpression:
viewModel::getResult
```

I know that right now it's looks strange that I don't use the returned value, but I will use it later :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a whole stack trace for the exception? Also, what is the point of this `try`?  Do you try to catch the exception from `getResult()`? Then it won't catch it. You don't invoke this function in `try`, you only create a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

From the error I would conclude that the error is that there is a NullPointerException in the call with "viewModel::getResult" and you don't catch that.

I also would expect a capital V for ViewModel.